# Appending API response to a single JSON file

Tags: python

How can I save the API response to a JSON File?
Note: content is a list with the sample Input to the API

```
import requests

url = "https://...fa50dd2c7ebdd7b74&q={}"

payload = {}
headers= {}

for i in range(0,len(content)):
 response = requests.request("GET", url.format(content[i]), headers=headers, data = payload)
 print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

I have tried with json.dump .. But it's not working

```
import requests

url = "https://...fa50dd2c7ebdd7b74&q={}"

payload = {}
headers= {}

for i in range(0,len(content)):
 response = requests.request("GET", url.format(content[i]), headers=headers, data = payload)
 with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(response.text.encode('utf8'),f)
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: have you try `response.json()`

Comment: @AlankarGupta I am getting this error.. Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable

Comment: @deadvoid I have tried that too.. but no luck.

Comment: if `response.json()` doesnt work for you, looks like `content-type` header is not `application/json`. you can first load response text as dict: `text = json.loads(response.text)` and then dump it to file, as you did: `json.dump(text, f)`